TL431-based battery discharger
I have built the following circuit on a breadboard, using a TI TL431BI (datasheet) and four 80 Ω resistors in series for the load (R3). Its eventual purpose is to slowly discharge a 4S LiIon battery to about 15.2 V.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Expected Behavior
I expect the TL431 to conduct when REF > Vref. In the simulation this switch happens when V1≈15.22 V.
In reality, it should be anywhere between 15.05 V and 15.20 V, based on my resistors' measured values (5.11 MΩ and 1.01 MΩ) and the TI TL431BI's Vref range of 2.483 V to 2.507 V (see datasheet, p. 13).

Actual Behavior
In practice, the TL431 starts/stops conducting when V1 ≈ 17.3 V.
I have eliminated R1 and R2 as a potential cause by meticulously measuring them and the resulting voltage divider's output voltage by itself, which behaves exactly as expected.
I then swapped out the TL431, but the new TL431 (same model) behaves exactly the same way.
What am I missing?

The TL431B is a bipolar part, with a substantial Vref input bias current. It is typically 2uA (maximum 4uA) under reference conditions. It's also temperature sensitive:

That's quite a bit of current for such a high-Z divider. Here's what my simulation shows (magenta trace is your resistor values, green trace is 1000x smaller):


After some more research, the NCP431 (https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp431-d.pdf) seems to be a better choice for my application. It has a typical reference input current of 81 nA (max. 190 nA). Please see the following link for screenshots of the relevant datasheet  info and a simulation based on the PSpice model provided by ON: https://i.imgur.com/yPLOt5w.jpeg
I don't fully grasp this topic, so I'd be glad if you could confirm/deny my assumption that the NCP431 would be suitable.

Since all the bias current for the reference has to come through your R1 and voltage is fixed at ~2.5V, you can approximate the error by multiplying R1 by the bias current. For the NCP431 and using your 5.1MΩ it will be less than 1V (typical ~0.4V). Maybe you also want to reduce R1 and R2 by 10:1 or so.
